# Using Stanford CoreNLP Python Parser for specific output

Tags: python, nlp, pos-tagger, stanford-nlp

I'm using [SCP](https://github.com/dasmith/stanford-corenlp-python) to get the parse CFG tree for English sentences.

```
from corenlp import *
corenlp = StanfordCoreNLP()
corenlp.parse("Every cat loves a dog")
```

My expected output is a tree like this:

```
(S (NP (DET Every) (NN cat)) (VP (VT loves) (NP (DET a) (NN dog))))
```

But what i got is:

```
(ROOT (S (NP (DT Every) (NN cat)) (VP (VBZ loves) (NP (DT a) (NN dog)))))
```

How to change the POS tag as expected and remove the ROOT node?

Thanks

Comment: Where are you getting your expected output from? The POS tags aren't the [Penn Treebank tags](http://www.comp.leeds.ac.uk/ccalas/tagsets/upenn.html) that CoreNLP parses into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [nltk.tree](http://www.nltk.org/howto/tree.html) module from [NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/).

```
from nltk.tree import *

def traverse(t):
    try:
        # Replace Labels
        if t.label() == "DT":
            t.set_label("DET")
        elif t.label() == "VBZ":
            t.set_label("VT")   
    except AttributeError:
        return

    for child in t:
        traverse(child)

output_tree= "(ROOT (S (NP (DT Every) (NN cat)) (VP (VBZ loves) (NP (DT a) (NN dog)))))"
tree = ParentedTree.fromstring(output_tree)

# Remove ROOT Element
if tree.label() == "ROOT":  
    tree = tree[0]

traverse(tree)
print tree  
# (S (NP (DET Every) (NN cat)) (VP (VT loves) (NP (DET a) (NN dog))))
```

Comment: Thanks, but how to transform the tree output to plain string (1-line string)? What i have is a tree with multi-lines and many redundant space...

Thanks!

Comment: Final "print tree" output comes in one line only. you can check - new_tree = str(tree); OR you can also use new_tree = re.sub("[\s]+"," ", str(tree));

Comment: Try to set a large enough margin, e.g. `t.pformat(margin=10000000)`